# php data base conntion echo confusing for following code

Tags: php, mysqli

in my php i call database connection from other php but i got confuse here its not echo current php echo

this my db.php code

```
<?php
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Database {
    private $con;
    public function connect (){
        include_once("constant.php");
        $this->con = new Mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        if ($this->con->connect_error) {
            echo"connect fails";
            //return $this->con;    
        }else{echo "connection success";}
        //return "DATABASE_CONNECTION_FAIL";

    }
}
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
?>
```

and this my user.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * user class for account creation and login purpose
 */
class User {
    private $con;
    function __construct(){

        include_once("../database/db.php");  
        $db = new Database();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
        if($this->con) {
        echo "connect databases";
      }
    }


}
$obj = new User();
?>
```

in my browser i call user.php but i got echo as `connection success connection success` its repeat 2 time but in user.php echo not display

my expect echo is `connect databases`

[image]

Comment: Look at the last lines in your database file. There it already makes a connection. Remove these lines and it'll be just once

Comment: you're calling connect() method two times

Comment: `$db->connect();` gets called twice, so naturally it will echo twice.

Comment: i remove in user.php same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your **user.php** calls the **connect()** function in your **Database** class. This also echoes the first *"connection success"* string:

```
$this->con = $db->connect();
```

This line in your **user.php** calls again the **connect()** function in your **Database** class, and prints the second *"connection success"* string.

```
if($this->con) { ... }
```

These lines in your **user.php** does not work because **connect()** function does not return anything:

```
if($this->con) {
  echo "connect databases";
}
```

You can replace your echoes in your **Database** class if-else block with **return** statements like this if you only want the *"connect databases"* string result:

```
if ($this->con->connect_error) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your connection is success. you should return the connection.

try this below db.php code

```
<?php
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Database {

  private $con;

  public function connect() {
    include_once("constant.php");
    $this->con = new Mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
    if ($this->con->connect_error) {
      echo"connect fails";
    }
    else {
      // return successful connection
      return $this->con;
    }
  }

}

$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
?>
```